# can't insert in database

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

In following application i can't able to insert data in database can you figure out what's the problems here actually inserting data null here when want to insert some data.

```
Handler class

@RestController
public class ISAController {

  @Autowired
  private ISAService isaService;

  @PostMapping("/createISA")
  public ISAModel createISA(ISAModel isaModel) {
      return isaService.createISA(isaModel);
  }
}

//repository interface

public interface ISARepository extends CrudRepository<ISAModel, Long>{

}

//service class

public interface ISAService {


    public ISAModel createISA(ISAModel isaModel);
    ISAModel updateISA(ISAModel isaModel);
    ISAModel deleteISA(ISAModel isaModel);
}

public interface ISAService {

    Optional<ISAModel> getAllISAInfoById(Long id);
    public ISAModel createISA(ISAModel isaModel);
    ISAModel updateISA(ISAModel isaModel);
    ISAModel deleteISA(ISAModel isaModel);
}

@Service
public class ISAServiceImpl implements ISAService{

    @Autowired
    private ISARepository iSARepository;

    @Override
    public Optional<ISAModel> getAllISAInfoById(Long id) {

        return iSARepository.findById(id);
    }
    @Override
    public ISAModel createISA(@RequestBody ISAModel isaModel) {
        return iSARepository.save(isaModel);
    }

    @Override
    public ISAModel updateISA(ISAModel isaModel) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ISAModel deleteISA(ISAModel isaModel) {

        return null;
    }
}
//model class
@Entity
class ISAModel{

 @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String salary;
}

//properties file
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root


## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

//main class like normal spring boot class with @EnableJpaAuditing annotation
```

in above application data is not going to database and showing null data stored there except id and id inserted here like 1 then 2 and so on...
i have edited above code so now.

Comment: what does the ISAModel class look like and how does the request that you send look like?

Comment: What does the implementation of ISAService look like?

Comment: I have updated code above kindly revert back asap.

Answer (score 0):

The @RequestBody annotation must be on the RestController not on the Service:

```
 @PostMapping("/createISA")
 public ISAModel createISA(@RequestBody ISAModel isaModel) {
```